# Setting a div's height to 70%

Tags: html, css

I have a super simple page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/ui/all.min.css")" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>   
    <div class="header">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
.header
{
    height:70%;
    width:100%;
    background:#990663;
}

body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

*
{
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

I want the div height to be 70% of screen. How can I achieve that? If I put 400px in height, it works. So why not 70%? Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to update `html` to have a 100% height (as well as `body`):

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wYNG/))

This is because `100%` is always relative to the **parent** container (for `body` that's `html`).

One [helpful post on the topic is here](http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/index.php/100-height-layout-using-css/comment-page-5/). FTA:

> First, we need to give 100% height to both the html and the body tag.
>   This is often overlooked but is vitally important as no element will
>   adjust to a percentage height unless it knows what it’s parent height
>   is currently occupying. As the container is a descendant of the body
>   tag which is a descendant of the html tag, then this is required.

Answer (score 1):

Just add 100% to the height of the HTML, and you'll have it sorted.

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
```

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/KYWKg/)